# Browser JSON vs node JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm attempting to serialize a string that contains escaped strings into JSON.  I would have imagined that `JSON.stringify()` would correctly re-escape those strings and allow me to `JSON.parse` it.  In a simple case, for example:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify("\\"))
```

The output from node is "\".  The output from the browser is "\" - it seems the browser (chrome in my case) is not correctly converting the double backslash `\\` into `\\\\`.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write code, you have to write `"\\"` (because backslash self is used as escaping), which is a string contains only one backslash (`"\\".length` is `1`).

But when displayed in console or browser, it will displayed as `"\"`.

Comment: Yes, it seems like its just that the console is eating them up for the display.  I later tried JSON.stringify("\\").length = 4 to confirm that it in fact is consistent with what I expect.